# Error in Auth0 ManagementClient function getUserBlocks

Tags: node.js, express, rest, auth0

My code works with this function:

```
// Function to retrieve the Guardians Enrollments (MFA)

function getMFAEnrollments(auth0Client, auth0UserId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        auth0Client.getGuardianEnrollments({ id: auth0UserId }).then((enrollments) => {
            resolve(enrollments);
        }).catch((err) => {
            const errMFA = {
                code: 'scim_error_MFA_getGuardianEnrollments',
                message: 'Error: Unable to retrieve the enrollments!',
                details: err
            };
            reject(errMFA);
        });
    });
}
```

But when I tried with another function from the same class (that seems to work the same way [see auth0 docs](https://auth0.github.io/node-auth0/ManagementClient.html#getUserBlocks)), my request returns an error: "auth0Client.getUserBlocks is not a function"

```
// Function to retrieve the User's Blocks (brute-force)

function getBlocksById(auth0Client, auth0UserId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        auth0Client.getUserBlocks({ id: auth0UserId }).then((blocks) => {
            resolve(blocks);
        }).catch((err) => {
            const errBlocks = {
                code: 'scim_error_Blocks_getUserBlocks',
                message: 'Error: Unable to retrieve blocks!',
                details: err
            };
            reject(errBlocks);
        });
    });
}
```

Anybody knows why this is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By your docs that you leaved with link, I think there would be problem depend on your application design structures

getGuardianEnrollments is belong to **UserManager** (provides methods for getting user information and impersonating users)  and getUserBlocks is belong to **ManagementClient**. It seems to be ManagementCLient and UserManager are seperate modules or classes of your app. To call getUserBlocks function just pass ManagementCLient instances to ***getBlocksById()*** function